# How to Update BIOS (DV7-1133cl) without WIndows with a USB drive?

Tags: usb, updates, bios

The BIOS on this HP is F.27 and I've already downloaded the latest compatible BIOS version (F.49). I extracted the files (which gave me several more .exe files), but I have no idea how to make them work within Ubuntu. I have read about some people using USB drives to make some sort of pretend-floppy drive and using some of the files from the original .exe to do this, but I have no idea what the specifics to the process are, and I'm not going to take the chance of bricking my computer until I understand a lot more about it.
Does anyone know how to or have resources to learn about this process (using a USB drive to update this type of BIOS)?